# Google Map addDomListener function parameter

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary

I want to get parameter from function

```
function initialize(myPin,myCen) {
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myPin);
   var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(myCen) }
   ....
}
```

I have my Pin(lat,long) and Map center(lat,long)

```
myPin = 12345,12345;
myCen = 12355,12355;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(myPin,MyCen);
```

Result
not work
please help

Answer (score 1):

The [google.maps.event.addDomListener function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) takes a function pointer as its argument.  You can use a pointer to an anonymous function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  initialize(myPin,MyCen)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
window.onload=function() {
    google.maps.event.initialize(myPin,MyCen);
}
```